# How to transform a data column to reduce the characters

Tags: r, transformation

I am working with a data set that has a column with values that I would like to transform.
The problem that I have right now is that my data looks like:

> 1. Site   Count
> 2. 1 1     35
> 3. 1 10    38
> 4. 1 2     56
> 5. 1 3     23
> 6. 1 4     25
> 7. 1 5     45
> 8. .......

I would like to remove the 1 that is present in all the sites and just leave it 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... 10.

I tried to transform it using as.number but it gives me the site 1.10 as the second value so it is not right.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example dataset:

```
dat = data.frame(site = paste(1, 1:10), 
                 count = round(runif(10, 1, 10)))
```

To get rid of the `1` bit:

```
dat$site = sub("1 ", "", dat$site)
```

Here I use `sub` to substitute the `1` by an empty string. The transformation to numeric then works:

```
dat$site = as.numeric(dat$site)
> dat$site
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: If this is what you need, to you mind checking this as the correct answer. It is the check mark right below the up/down vote button.

Comment: Thank you Paul, it worked but the data frame that I have is like 250 rows of data, I removed the 1 but now when I tried to order the data it orders like 1,10,100,101,102, 103,104.....

Comment: Did you convert to numeric first? Characters are ordered in the way you show.

Comment: yes they are numeric but I am not sure why it still shows 10 and 100 before 2, do I have to convert them to 001, 002...?

Comment: Could you update your question with a piece of R code which reproduces this problem?

Comment: ok I will try but I extracted my data from an xml file so if I just create the data frame then I don't have the same problem. Let me try to reproduce the problem creating a code but thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Paul Sorry for my ignorance but I double checked the values and they where characters and not numeric. I transformed and everything is perfect now. Thanks again and sorry for the confusion